# using .each with closest()

Tags: jquery, each

I am trying to loop through a bunch of fields in a form and need to change the link text.

My desired result is

```
Alert("Second 1");
Alert("Second 2");
```

Example code:

```
<div class="text-wrapper">
    <input class="field-text" value="">
</div>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="" class="first">First</li>
        <li><a href="" class="second">Second 1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="text-wrapper">
    <input class="field-text" value="">
</div>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="" class="first">First</li>
        <li><a href="" class="second">Second 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".text-wrapper").each(function(){
            var value = jQuery(this).closest("a.second").text();
            alert(value);
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: none of your div with class 'text-wrapper' has a anchor tag with class'second'.

Comment: Why aren't you just targeting the CSS class "second"?

Comment: @user: Did you read [the documentation for `.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) before using it?

Comment: try this var value = $(this).find("a.second").text(); ...closest() traverses up the DOM tree.

Comment: You forgot to close your `<a>` tags.

Answer (score 5):

`closest` finds the parent that matches the selector, not the child.

You want `find` instead.

EDIT: `find` won't work, as the tag your looking for isn't a child of `text-wrapper`.  You need to manually traverse the DOM to find the element.

```
jQuery(this).next('div').find("a.second").text();
```

Comment: Even so `.text-wrapper` is not a parent of `a.second`

Comment: here's a jsfiddle of this solution, i was going to make an answer, but your edit beat me to it :)   http://jsfiddle.net/QFgun/

for some reason the 2nd links text is coming up as blank.

Comment: @Patricia: It's because of OP's broken markup. The missing `</a>` tags are causing the browser to guess at an interpretation that isn't what OP wants.

Comment: aha!  i thought it was a markup problem, but for some reason didn't see the missing </a> of course! fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QFgun/1/

Answer (score 3):

`closest()` walks UP the DOM tree starting with the node itself, then it's parentNode, the parentNode's parentNode, and so forth.
The function you are looking for is `find()` which searches the descendants of a given node.

Edit for completeness:

Since `a.second` is not a descendant of `.text-wrapper` you will first have to call `next()`, which returns `.text-wrapper`'s next sibling, i.e. the div element containing `a.second`.

```
jQuery(this).next().find('a.second').text()
```

Comment: `a.second` isn't a child of `.text-wrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

Full jsFiddle of the working solution, including both links showing in the console log: http://jsfiddle.net/3rH63/

Comment: Please post your solution here instead of just on a different site. It ensures that future readers can benefit from your answer if that link ever breaks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as per test case you provided. You have not closed  tag properly which you to have close before trying below code:

```
$("div:odd").each(function(){
    var value = $(this).find("a.second").html();
    alert(value);
});
```

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/harshithjv/2ePn9/1/